# How do you submit a form in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a simple form, you select a color and input a quantity. When you click the submit button, I want to replace `index.html` partial with the `submitted.html` partial and work with the information submitted from the form. In `SubmittedCtrl` I will be using the information to make an api call and the returning data will be used within `submitted.html` partial.

**index.html partial**

```
<form>
    <select ng-model="input.Color" ng-options="product as product.color for product in products"></select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="input.Qty">
    <button ng-click="submit(input)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: './partials/index.html',
            controller: 'IndexCtrl'
        })
        .when('/submitted', {
            templateUrl: './partials/submitted.html',
            controller: 'SubmittedCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            template: "404 not found"
        })
});

myApp.controller("IndexCtrl", function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.submit = function(data) {
        $http.jsonp('http://api.remoteserver/' + data.Color.color + '/' + data.Qty + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
                .success(function(result) {
                //how do I get this data loaded into SubmittedCtrl?
        });
    }
});

myApp.controller("SubmittedCtrl", function($scope, $routeParams) {

});
```

Comment: Read the documentation of the $http service. You'll use it to send an AJAX request with $scope.input (presumably) as its data.

Comment: I already have the $http service working for the remote api call. What I don't get is how do I take that data from within IndexCtrl and load the submitted.html partial with it.

Comment: what I would suggest is create a service to make the AJAX call and store the returned data within callabck of $http to another variable in your service. As you store data use $location to change path. Inject service into both controllers. When path changes `submitCtrloer` has data sititng and waiting in service. I've never inspected what's available on submit button...have always use `ng-submit` on form. Data from form is already bound to your your scope object as a resultof `ng-model` which already created  `$scope.input`

Comment: OOps..always give form a name . Is used to create validation object that is automatically created on forms by angular

Comment: Here's a [crude demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YqZFBAtQlcWk3LBny7Zg?p=preview) of above concept using $timeout to mock long AJAX delay. Includes disabling of submit button using angular automatically created validation object

Comment: thanks, that is pretty close to working. When I replace the timeout with the actual ajax call, setting this.store = ajax result doesn't seem to go through to the next page.